# ModuleNotFoundError when using python venv even though pip freeze shows the packages are installed

Tags: python, python-venv

I am new to venv and virtual environments for Python in general. I created an environment called .venv using:

```
python3 -m venv .venv
```

I then activated it and installed some packages. When I list the packages using `pip freeze`, I get the following:

```
(.venv) $ pip freeze
boto==2.48.0
bz2file==0.98
certifi==2017.7.27.1
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
...
```

However, if I try to import any of these packages, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`, e.g.:

```
(.venv) $ python -c 
"import click"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'click'
```

What am I missing???

Comment: The first `venv` is named (.venv) and the second one is named (.venv2). Is this intentional?

Comment: `python` (with no appended version number) usually still points to `python2`, instead try `python3 -c 
"import click"`

Comment: @downshift: In a virtualenv, `python` usually points to whatever the Python version for that virtualenv is.

Comment: Can you please show the output of `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'` ? Also, please do `which pip` & `which python` -- are they from the same venv & dir?

Comment: thank you for correcting me (in my experience with `venv` I get executables of all python versions on my system. Obviously I'm using `venv` incorrectly! ;-) ) @jwodder

Comment: ['', '/home/rob/anaconda3/lib/python36.zip', '/home/rob/anaconda3/lib/python3.6', '/home/rob/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/rob/ai/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']

Comment: `which pip` and `which python` come from the same as the last .venv path shown above.